# Netbeans 8.0.1 package javax.microedition.lcdui.* does not exist

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lcdui

I get an error while using import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

package javax.microedition.lcdui.* does not exist.

But the line import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;

does not give any error.

Answer (score 0):

Imoprt lcdui jar file in your application library. You can download this jar file from here. [Download Jar file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmidp21jar.htm)

Comment: i still get the error. I added the midp.jar to lib folder  and used the import statement.

Comment: share piece of import packages and full stacktrace of errors.

Comment: The error:<br/>Compiling 1 source file to e:\jmeapp\JavaMEApplication12\build\classes
e:\jmeapp\JavaMEApplication12\src\javameapplication12\JavaMEApplication12.java:9: error: package javax.microedition.lcdui does not exist
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
1 error
e:\jmeapp\JavaMEApplication12\nbproject\build-impl.xml:432: The following error occurred while executing this line:
e:\jmeapp\JavaMEApplication12\nbproject\build-impl.xml:253: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)  <br/> The import statement import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

Comment: I suggest you create new project and move all source to new project and compile your code. **Note**  Make sure you have added all library in you library path of project.